# Perform function on multiple records using textacy

Tags: python, function, textacy

I am attempting to extract quotations and quotation attributions from text across multiple records using a function from textacy.
So far, I have successfully executed the function on a single record, as such:

```
import textacy

data = ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 1")

doc = textacy.make_spacy_doc((data), lang="en_core_web_sm")

quotes = textacy.extract.triples.direct_quotations(doc)

print(list(quotes))
```

This is the output:

> [DQTriple(speaker=[world], cue=[said], content="Hello, nice to meet you,")]

But I run into errors when I attempt to run the function on multiple records. Here is what I have tried:

```
import textacy

data = [
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 1"),
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 2"),
        ]

doc = textacy.make_spacy_doc((data), lang="en_core_web_sm")

quotes = textacy.extract.triples.direct_quotations(doc)

print(list(quotes))
```

And the error message:

> raise TypeError(errors.type_invalid_msg("data", type(data), types.DocData))
> TypeError: `data` type = <class 'list'> is invalid; type must match typing.Union[str, textacy.types.Record, spacy.tokens.doc.Doc].

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = [
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 1"),
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 2"),
        ]
for record in data:
    doc = textacy.make_spacy_doc(record, lang="en_core_web_sm")
    print(list(textacy.extract.triples.direct_quotations(doc)))
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72561534/2) to the question [Perform function on multiple records using textacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561534/perform-function-on-multiple-records-using-textacy) by the OP [jedmund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19146242/jedmund) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>